# Using jquery to detect change in a form

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

Loading the latest jquery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Script to detect a change in the form:

```
<script>
    $('#myform').on('keyup change', 'input, select, textarea', function(){
        console.log('Form changed');
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<form id="myform" action="..." method="post">
    <input ....................>
    <input ....................>
</form>
```

Nothing appears in the console and so it is not picking up a change in the form. Can anyone tell me what I have got wrong here?

Comment: Seems fine. https://jsfiddle.net/kewghwev/1/

Comment: I agree your fiddle works - why not on my site?

Comment: Check for any script errors that might be affecting the functionality

Comment: Make sure you use $(document).ready().

`$(document).ready(function(){
$('#myform').on('keyup change', 'input, select, textarea', function(){
        console.log('Form changed');
    });
});`

Comment: Perfect thanks. That was the problem.